# Hadoop on Mesos fails with "Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MesosExecutor"

Tags: hadoop, mesos

I have a Mesos cluster setup -- I have verified that the master can see the slaves -- but when I attempt to run a Hadoop job, all tasks wind up with a status of LOST.  The same error is present in all the slave stderr logs:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MesosExecutor
```

and that is the only line in the stderr logs.

Following the instructions on http://mesosphere.io/learn/run-hadoop-on-mesos/, I have put a modified Hadoop distribution on HDFS which each slave can access.
In the `lib` directory of the Hadoop distribution, I have added `hadoop-mesos-0.0.4.jar` and `mesos-0.14.2.jar`.

I have verified that each slave does in fact download this Hadoop distribution, and that `hadoop-mesos-0.0.4.jar` contains the class `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MesosExecutor`, so I cannot figure out why the class cannot be found.

I am using Hadoop from CDH4.4.0 and mesos-0.15.0-rc4.

Does any one have any suggestions as to what might be the problem?  I know I would always start with a `CLASSPATH` problem, but, in this case, the mesos-slave is downloading, unpacking, and attempting to run a Hadoop TaskTracker so I would imagine any `CLASSPATH` would be setup by the mesos-slave.

In the stdout of the slave logs, the environment is printed.  There is a `MESOS_HADOOP_HOME` which is empty.  Should this be set to something?  If it is supposed to be set to the downloaded Hadoop distribution, I cannot set it in advance because the Hadoop distribution is downloaded to a new location every time.

In the event that is related (some permissions issue maybe), when attempting to browse slave logs via the master UI, I get the error `Error browsing path: ...`.
The user running mesos-slave can browse to the correct directory when I do so manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.  `bin/hadoop` of the downloaded Hadoop distribution attempts to find its location by running `which $0`.  However, that will find a current Hadoop installation if one exists (i.e. `/usr/lib/hadoop`), and will load the jars under that installation's `lib` directory instead of the downloaded one's `lib` directory.

I had to modify `bin/hadoop` of the downloaded distribution to find its own location with `dirname $0` instead of `which $0`.